# How do I send a notification to another user active when update?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

I have an application with one DB which is used by many users. Whenever one user makes changes, we save the changes to the database.

Now, I need to notify other logged-in users about this change. How can this be done?

I'm thinking - when the application succcessfully saves / updates the data in the database, the application will send a notification to the connected clients with the new record updated or added.

I'm using C# and SQL Server database.

Comment: Is this a web application? Do you have a service layer between your clients and database?

Comment: isnt web application, but windows form application dude..

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate options are push-based notifications with something like a message bus, or polling loops on known ids.

Message busses operate on publish-subscribe models which work well for Windows applications. Have a look at MassTransit or MSMQ as a starting point. There are plenty of options out there. They can be combined into web apps using something that essentially wraps a polling loop with the client like SignalR.

Polling-based options work typically on a timer and do quick timestamp or version # checks against the database, reloading a record if a difference is found.

Push-based are more efficient but only notify of changes between supported applications. (Client to Client) they don't detect changes by applications that don't participate as publishers, nor do they see changes made directly to the database.

Polling-based options cover all changes, but are generally slower and require a schema that has version information to work effectively.